# i can't use inner join and left join together

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i used inner join and left join together in follow query but result is just left join between PostTags and PostXTags.
what is my problem?

```
from pt in db.PostTags
                   join xp in
                       (
                           from x in db.PostXTags
                           join p in db.Posts
                           on x.PostID equals p.PostID
                           where p.PostID == postID
                           select x
                           )
                   on pt.PostTagID equals xp.PostTagID into g
                   from ptxp in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where (pt.BlogID == blogID && pt.Type == PostTags.Type.Category)
                   select pt;
```

Answer (score 0):

EF uses INNER JOIN when two tables are associated 1 <-> * (or 1 <-> 1).
In other cases LEFT OUTER JOIN is used, generally.
If there is no association between the entities, LEFT OUTER JOIN will be used as well.